# is it possible to insert xml fragments in xml typed columns sql server 2008

Tags: xml, insert, typed

While creating a table that has an XML type column, I am referring to a complex XML Schema Collection. When I specify the XML Schema, I do not specify the option of DOCUMENT or CONTENT assuming a default value of CONTENT.

I am able to insert the xml data which has top level node, but unable to insert other xml fragments.

Please see the xml fragment and schema mentioned below

  Insertion of xml fragment

```
INSERT INTO [testdb].[dbo].[dummy6]
           ([ItemData])
     VALUES
           ('
  <shipto xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="shipto.xsd">
    <name>Ola Nordmann</name>
    <address>Langgt 23</address>
    <city>4000 Stavanger</city>
    <country>Norway</country>
  </shipto>');
```

  Schema

```
DROP XML SCHEMA COLLECTION shipOrderCollection
CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION shipOrderCollection AS 
'
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="shiporder">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="orderperson" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="shipto">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="item" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="note" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="quantity" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
            <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="orderid" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

'
;
GO